# jest installation in node getting error gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir 'build'

Tags: node.js, node-modules, jestjs, permission-denied, node-gyp

I tried to install jest by running following command.

```
sudo npm install -g jest
```

It resulted in an error, to fix this I have tried following commands.

1. Tried to update node-gyp to latest version.
   `npm explore npm -g -- npm install node-gyp@latest`
2. Ran following commands to resolve any access problem.

   `sudo chown -R $USERNAME:$GROUP ~
   sudo chown -R $USERNAME:$GROUP /usr/local//lib/node_modules/
   sudo chown -R $USERNAME:$GROUP /usr/local/Cellar/node/`

I am using macbook and tried to install in folder under my home directory.
I am new to node, any help to resolve is much appreciated.

Following error was thrown :

```
node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(undefined): https://fsevents- 
binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.1.3/fse-v1.1.3-node-v59- 
darwin-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for fsevents@1.1.3 and 
node@9.9.0 (node-v59 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile 
with node-gyp)
gyp ERR! clean error
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir 'build'
gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.5.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/9.9.0/bin/node" 
"/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node- 
gyp.js" "clean"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/jest/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v9.9.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 
'/usr/local/Cellar/node/9.9.0/bin/node 
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js 
clean' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> 
(/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jest/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/
node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:180:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose 
(internal/child_process.js:936:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit 
(internal/child_process.js:220:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.5.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/9.9.0/bin/node" 
"/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jest/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/
node-pre-gyp/bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd 
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jest/node_modules/fsevents
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v9.9.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.39
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute '/usr/local/Cellar/node/9.9.0/bin/node 
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js 
clean' (1)
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 
(node_modules/jest/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 
install: `node install`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1
```

Answer (score -1):

try this command:

sudo npm install -g --unsafe-perm